# CORS enabled URLs dont work for AWS Healthcheck

Tags: deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-cors-headers

I have an Elastic Beanstalk Application to host my Django Rest Framework End points.

I have enabled corsheader to protect Cross origin request forgery.
Now the problem is when health check on ELB occurs it sends a request on health url via :80/api/health/ but this URL throws 400 Bad request since the URL via any domain except once specified in allowed_host are not allowed.

I tried putting in allowed_host as ["172.*", "192.*", "10.*", "*.mydomina.com"]

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I raised this as a ticket with AWS support and found a solution as
https://dryan.com/articles/elb-django-allowed-hosts/

Make Changes to your production configuration as

```
# Add Private IP of the ELB Instance to Allowed Host for the Health check not to throw CORS 400 Bad Request
EC2_PRIVATE_IP = None
try:
  EC2_PRIVATE_IP = requests.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4', timeout=0.01).text
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
  pass

if EC2_PRIVATE_IP:
  ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(EC2_PRIVATE_IP)

  print("Allowed Host List:")
  print(ALLOWED_HOSTS)
```